# Count DIFFDATE Exceeding A Specified Value - Step 3

Tags: sql

Along the same vein as the questions asked yesterday, I have another "count if" dilemma.  Now I need to pull a count of the condition entries that meet the following parameters:

1. ConditionLevelEntryID = 189
2. CheckoffDate is > 14 days from ConditionEntryDateTime
3. CheckoffDate IS NULL and ConditionEntryDateTime is > 14 days old

I have attempted the query (below) which doesn't work.  The error returned is below the query.  Please help me refine the query to get an accurate count.  Thanks in advance.

```
select Count(*)
from conditionentrytable c
where conditionlevelentryid=189
    and 
    ((c.checkoffdate IS NULL 
    and 
    convert(varchar(12),DATEADD(day,14,c.conditionentrydatetime)))
    or 
    DATEDIFF(dd,c.checkoffdate,c.conditionentrydatetime)>14)
```

> Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1,
>   Line 7 Line 7: Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    conditionentrytable c
WHERE   conditionlevelentryid=189
        AND DATEDIFF(dd, COALESCE(c.checkoffdate, GETDATE()),c.conditionentrydatetime) > 14
```

, or even better:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    conditionentrytable c
WHERE   conditionlevelentryid=189
        AND c.conditionentrydatetime > COALESCE(c.checkoffdate, GETDATE()) - 14
```

The latter query will use a composite index on `(conditionlevelentryid, conditionentrydatetime)` if you have one, which will most probably greatly improve the query performance.

Answer (score 1):

A little rusty myself but there's nothing being done with the converted conditionentrydatetime in the IS NULL expression.

How about?

```
select Count(*)
from conditionentrytable c
where conditionlevelentryid=189
    and 
    ((c.checkoffdate IS NULL 
    and 
    DATEDIFF(dd,getdate(),c.conditionentrydatetime)>14)
    or 
    DATEDIFF(dd,c.checkoffdate,c.conditionentrydatetime)>14))
```